# Modeling Urns and Balls System as a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, expected-value, markov-chain-montecarlo, stochastic-processes

Suppose I have $q$ urns each of which hold up to $n$ distinguishable balls, but only $1$ of each type of ball (there being $n$ types of balls too). I would like to make any particular configuration of the number of balls in the urns equally likely, with each urn having at least 1 ball. Importantly, I am trying to make sure that the number of balls in any of the urns (no matter what type of ball) be equally likely, *not* that any individual type of ball be equally likely to be in the urns. I believe this is represented by this distribution
$$
P(U) = \frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^q{n \choose n_i}} = \prod\limits_{i=1}^q\frac{n_i!\left(n-n_i\right)!}{n!}
$$

where $1\leq n_i\leq n$ is the number of balls in urn $i$.

I would like to calculate the mean number of balls in the urns of this distribution but I am not sure how to do this analytically. My idea is to do a monte carlo simulation for given $n$ and $q$ to gain some intuition and to see how peaked (or not) the distribution is.

Is this sampling scheme a valid way to sample from $P(U)$:

1. Choose an urn uniformly at random
2. If the urn has fewer than $n$ balls and more than $1$ ball, add a ball of a type not already in the urn (at random) with probability $1/2$, otherwise remove a ball from the urn at random.
3. If the urn has only 1 ball, add a ball of a type not already in the urn (at random) with probability $1/2$, otherwise, do nothing.
4. If the urn has $n$ balls, remove a ball  with probability $1/2$, otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: It is not clear what is $U$, what are the random variables, and how did you came up with that expression for the distribution. You also wrote that each urn holds $n$ balls but then that $n_i$ is the number of balls in urn $i$. Which one is true  ?

Comment: oops, I made a mistake. I meant "up to" $n$ balls. I have corrected it in the post. $U$ is a random vector of the number of balls in each of the urns. so $U = \{2,3,3\}$ means there are $2$ balls in urn 1, $3$ balls in urn 2, and $3$ balls in urn 3.

Comment: Ok, but then your distribution implies that the $n_i$'s are independent, and different configuration are not equally likely as you wanted - e.g. $(1,1,1)$ is more likely then $(3,3,3)$ if $n=3$

Comment: I think I’m having an issue with language. If make $U$ a binary $n \times q$ matrix such that $U_{ir}$  = 1 if a ball of type $i$ is in urn $r$ then I believe the probability of generating a particular $U$ where any  number of $1$s in a column is equally likely follows the distribution I’ve written. And yes, I am assuming independence in the columns. Does this sound correct?

Comment: That is a bit clearer, but if you construct $P(U)$ such that is gives equal probability for each value of $n_i$ , then $n_i$ is just uniformly distributed  between 1 and $n$, and the mean is therefore $(n+1)/2$. Is that what you are trying to get ?

Comment: That does make sense. Does my sampling scheme seem like the proper way to get the distribution of the possible $U$ matrices, I'd like to take a closer look?

Comment: It might work, it's not immediately obvious to me. But you can also easily sample this distribution directly : just pick $n_i$ uniformly between 1 and $n$, then randomly choose $n_i$ different ball types from the $n$ possible values